# Browser extension download a file to a hidden sub-directory raise an invalid filename error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I want to download a file into a hidden directory (e.g. `.data/demo.txt`).

Using the `browser.downloads.download` or `chrome.downloads.download` API:

```
//running in background script
browser.downloads.download({
  url: 'https://example.org/demo.txt',
  filename: '.data/demo.txt',
  saveAs: false
});
```

I've tried this code both on Firefox and Chrome, both raised an invalid filename Error. If I change filename to `data/demo.txt`, it works fine. I can't get any details about this in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download).

Does this API support download a file to a hidden sub-directory? How to fix this, if it supports?

Comment: Is your code running in content script or in background script?

Answer (score 0):

here is the wrong :  filename: '.data/demo.txt',

you can use :  filename: 'data/demo.txt',

only ~/download can be use as root dirctory in chrome.